# Average and group by in SQL but for best 10 records only

Tags: sql, limit, average, ranking, partition

Given: A ranking table (id, user_id, score, group_id, date)

Currently we calculate a ranking based on all participating users based on sum and average.

```
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(r.score)::NUMERIC, 2) AS score,
    SUM(score) AS score_sum,
    MAX(r.date) AS ranking_timestamp,
    a.name AS group_name,
    a.id AS group_id
FROM
ranking r, group a
WHERE a.id = r.group_id
GROUP BY a.id,a.name
ORDER BY AVG(r.score) DESC,MAX(r.date) ASC
```

Now we want to change that. Instead of honor all participating user, take the 10 best users only, calculate SUM and AVG.

Is that possible within one statement?

Comment: Best - according to what? And what about ties?

Comment: perhaps one approach is to use a sub query to get the best 10 and then run the grouping query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
WITH TEMP AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROUND(AVG(r.score)::NUMERIC, 2) AS score,
            SUM(score) AS score_sum,
            MAX(r.date) AS ranking_timestamp,
            a.name AS group_name,
            a.id AS group_id
        FROM
        ranking r, group a
        WHERE a.id = r.group_id
        GROUP BY a.id,a.name
        ORDER BY AVG(r.score) DESC,MAX(r.date) ASC
    )


SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TEMP ORDER BY score ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **TOP 10**

```
SELECT TOP 10
    ROUND(AVG(r.score)::NUMERIC, 2) AS score,
    SUM(score) AS score_sum,
    MAX(r.date) AS ranking_timestamp,
    a.name AS group_name,
    a.id AS group_id
FROM
ranking r, group a
WHERE a.id = r.group_id
GROUP BY a.id,a.name
ORDER BY AVG(r.score) DESC,MAX(r.date) ASC
```